# Why do Nusach Ashkenaz and Nusach Sefard have different ways of winding the arm tefillin?

Tags: tefilin, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard

I hope that I have the description correct, here:

Nusach Ashkenaz winds the arm tefillin toward the body, while Nusach Sefard winds it away from the body.

What is the origin of this difference, and why is there a difference?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Nusach of prayer.

Comment: The two directions are commonly associated with those _nuschaos_ and there's probably a positive correlation, but the demarcation lines between the _nuschaos_ and between the winding directions don't coincide exactly.

Comment: Or, in other words, your question is a fine one (whence the difference in direction?), but your naming is colloquial rather than accurate, so your hope expressed in your first sentence is unfulfilled.